# Проблема с window.print() javascript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, pdf, print

Когда нажимаю на кнопку которой присвоено функция window.print() javascript то она автоматически делает 2 страницы хотя всё помещается в одну, делает две одинаковые страницы тип повтор

Comment: Если вы приведёте полноценнны воспроизводимый пример - то найти проблему будет легче

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, если он приведёт воспроизводимый пример, то, вероятно, сможет сам и исправить)))

Answer (score 0):

Я знаю только 2 случая, в которых при печати html-разметка, существующая в одном экземпляре, отображается в нескольких:

- position: fixed
- заголовки таблиц

Вараинт с таблицами маловероятен - даже если у тебя табличная верстка, то вряд ли всё лежит в thead, а не tbody.

А вот что-нибудь в духе `body { position: fixed; }` можно поискать. Скорее всего, там суммарная высота чуть больше страницы - достаточно для появления второй (может даже что-то в дуже `body { height: 101% }` для форсирования скролла), а по контенту этого не заметно.